# I am not really clear about the meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning

She says that her love of adventure began when she was ten. She gives credit to her mom for planting the seed. "My mom found adventure books for me to read which had females actively involved in the story."

For this sentence, does credit mean praise and planting the seed mean to encourage her adventure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not entirely. Credit in this context means to acknowledge as the source of something. Planting the seed means to create the initial or the inception of the initial idea, gift, or talent. Like a flower, a person can plant an idea even though they do not actively foster, nurture, grow, or tend to it.